# Oracle Apex instance setting on Oracle Cloud

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I have this error while trying to upload file in my oracle apex application on oracle cloud:

> The instance does not allow unauthenticated users to upload files.

I login into the admin console to allow users to upload files but I don't see the security tab?

environmment:
Host:  oracle cloud
DB  :  18c
APEX : Application Express 19.1.0.00.15

[image]

Answer (score 5):

This [document](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/atp-cloud/atpug/apex-restrictions.html#GUID-E13D5044-B9DD-4168-8A12-C99532940DA9) addresses issues on what you can, or rather, cannot do as Instance Administrators. You are permitted to change what you have access to the web UI and SMTP parameters using the `APEX_INSTANCE_ADMIN` package.

Comment: Thanks @Adrian   png